# shows video which is not in my storage and deleted before

Tags: android, android-intent, mediastore

I am working on an android application, it has one feature to select video from storage and upload to cloud but when I trying to select video from my application it also shows video which is not in storage and deleted before.

Here is my code to select video

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    intent.setType("video/*");
    activity.startActivityForResult(intent, VIDEO_PICKER_REQUEST);
```

Answer (score 0):

`MediaStore` updating files is not immediate, because the file manager does not inform about the action to `MediaStore.`MediaStore will find out eventually after few hours. Try making a call after some time or update the `MediaStore` directly.